# Importing VLCKit (after c59cb1b) in a Swift based project

Tags: objective-c, swift, vlc

So I get the latest VLCKit to compile and I see in the xcode project it has it's `Defines Module` set to **Yes** in the project Build Settings, and it has the `Product Module Name` set to **VLCKit**.

I run `make VLCKit` to build the framework, everything builds and I get my VLCKit.framework file.

I embed that framework into my Swift based app.

If I use the bridging header, it complains that it can't find the VLCKit/VLCKit.h

from the swift side `import VLCKit` is also an error.

Anyone get this to work?

Comment: Well I managed to fix the issue by just creating a new project VLCKit won't play in my swift bridged project, which is another issue entirely. It will play in a purely obj-c project though.

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to fix the issue by just creating a new project VLCKit won't play in my swift bridged project, which is another issue entirely. It will play in a purely obj-c project though.